# When is report generated in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng

people!

I'd like to send report via email after test class finishes.
I know where the output is located so I tried to send email in @AfterSuite method but it sends old report.
So I tried to sleep for 2 seconds which didn't help.

Can you help me send report to mail automatically right after test class is done?

Comment: Instead of trying to do this inside your tests, why not have your build tool send the email?

Comment: Yeah, that came to my mind on the way from my apartment. Thanks, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following will helpful to you

https://www.guru99.com/pdf-emails-and-screenshot-of-test-reports-in-selenium.html

if you are using maven as a build tool
[http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/send-reports-automatically-to-email-using-maven-from-eclipse](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/send-reports-automatically-to-email-using-maven-from-eclipse/)